# Ubuntu - Create Script to Restart Multiple Tomcat Instances

Tags: linux, ubuntu, service, tomcat7

I have 4 instances of Tomcat to serve a JSP application. Every now and then I have to restart them all (when I recompile a class, for instance). But every time I have to restart their services one by one:

```
sudo service tomcat71 restart
sudo service tomcat72 restart
sudo service tomcat73 restart
sudo service tomcat74 restart
```

How can I put those commandis in a script so to run them all at once?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for num in {71..74}
do
  sudo service "tomcat$num" restart
done
```

You can change the `{71..74}` sequence if needed.

The same command on a single line:

```
 for num in {71..74}; do sudo service "tomcat$num" restart; done
```

(This might be more useful in an interactive shell — quicker to type).

More info:

- http://ss64.com/bash/for.html
- http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-brace-expansion